# Send invitation emails on post_save or all at once in django view?

Tags: python, django, email, notifications

There's a requirement in a web app I'm building about the possibility of the user sending join invitations to his friends. These invitations are stored in the database through the `Invitation` model. The user can send multiple invitations at once.

What do you think is more appropriate: sending all emails at once in the back end view or sending one at time in Invitation `post_save`?

Is there a substantial performance overhead to send one email at time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is live application and user experience is important, then I suggest you avoid sending anything email-related in post_save handlers, or even in views.

Reasons are: SMTP can go down, network connection can go down, network can be up but speed can be that of a snail etc. In each of those cases either your program breaks, or user waits and waits and waits... which is not good for business.

The solution is to write/buy/find separate email dispatcher that is able to handle all such situations gently, alert administrator in case of trouble, switch SMTP gates on the fly, additionally it could trace bounce-back etc.

Then, in your post_save handler, you only add something like this:

```
   email_dispatcher.add_to_queue(my_email)
```

Regarding ready-made solutions - quick scan of code.google com resulted in http://code.google.com/p/django-mailer/ but I haven't used it so cannot make recommendation.

Comment: django-mailer works great.  Just remember that all your mail is going into a queue and you have to have some sort of process running that clears said queue.  This is documented though.